# Ubuntu 18.04 boots only through recovery (old laptop with Intel Mobile 945GM)

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, graphics, data-recovery

I switched from 32 bit Ubuntu (where it worked just fine) to the newest 18.04. I own quite an old computer HP compaq nx6310 with Intel Mobile 945GM and now I am able to boot only through recovery. Is it a driver issue? Is it even compatible? Where to get that driver?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/laptops-and-netbooks/hp-compaq-nx6310-12093/review) your exact computer model?

Comment: It is modified now, it has new SSD disc and 4gb Ram but yes, this is it. In fact, the dics was changed between installing these two systems (the 32 bit was on HDD).

Answer (score 0):

Regular ubuntu no longer supports 32bit processors like yours unfortunately, you may want to consider trying Lubuntu 18.04 which still does.

Comment: How does it work please? Why am I able to install whole system and run it normally  through recovery if Ubuntu does not support this?